# Countdown timer in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, timer, cocos2d-iphone, countdown

I'm trying to create a countdown timer in cocos2d, but I can not help and would like to resolve this problem, my code is below this, perhaps the logic is wrong but I can not fix.

```
-(id) init
{
// always call "super" init
// Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
if( (self=[super init] )) {


    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"backgame.png"];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [background setPosition:ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2)];

    [self addChild: background];


    [self schedule:@selector(countDown:)];              
}
return self;
}

-(void)countDown:(ccTime)delta
{

CCLabel *text = [CCLabel labelWithString:@" " 
                                         fontName:@"BallsoOnTheRampage" fontSize:46];

text.position = ccp(160,455);
text.color = ccYELLOW;
[self addChild:text];

int countTime = 20;
while (countTime != 0) {
    countTime -= 1;
    [text setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countTime]];
} 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `int countTime = 20;` is declaring itself every time to be 20.  Also, your while loop will decrement the countTimer as fast as the system can update the CCLabel.  If you're trying to do a real timer, you want it to decrement ONLY when `countDown:` is called.  Not during a while-loop.

Try this:

```
@interface MyScene : CCLayer
{
   CCLabel *_text;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) int countTime;

@end

@implementation MyScene

@synthesize countTime = _countTime;

-(id) init {
    if( (self=[super init] )) {


    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"backgame.png"];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [background setPosition:ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2)];

    [self addChild: background];
    _countTime = 20;

    _text = [CCLabel labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.countTime] 
                                         fontName:@"BallsoOnTheRampage" fontSize:46];

    text.position = ccp(160,455);
    text.color = ccYELLOW;
    [self addChild:_text];

    [self schedule:@selector(countDown:) interval:0.5f];// 0.5second intervals



    }
return self;
}

-(void)countDown:(ccTime)delta {

   self.countTime--;
  [_text setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.countTime]];
  if (self.countTime <= 0) {

    [self unschedule:@selector(countDown:)];
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: Zebulon thanks for the reply, and Stephen with its code and its explanation won the day today, is working the way you expect much thanks for the help, I learned a lot now.

Comment: @gangmobile, don't forget you can check my answer as accepted. :D

Answer (score -1):

Your count allways becomes 20 in your countDown.

You should also move this to your init:

```
CCLabel *text = [CCLabel labelWithString:@" " 
                                     fontName:@"BallsoOnTheRampage" fontSize:46];
```

text.position = ccp(160,455);
text.color = ccYELLOW;
[self addChild:text];

Then you should use:

```
[self schedule:@selector(countDown:) interval:1.0f];
```

Then instead of using CCLabel you should use CCLabelBMFont. It's much faster :)

Comment: How to disable this schedule ?